# Calculate $δ_{ik}u_k$,$δ_{ij}δ_{ij}$

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, kronecker-product, kronecker-symbol

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I'm trying to understand some tensor/kronecker calculations that are something off-course :

> *Calculate the expressions :*
>
> $$δ_{ik}u_k,δ_{ij}δ_{ij}$$

So :

$$δ_{ik}u_k = u_i = u_1 + u_2 + u_3$$

$$δ_{ij}δ_{ij} = δ_{jj} = δ_{ii} = δ_{11} + δ_{22} + δ_{33} = 3$$

What I wanted to ask, is why does the solver always chose to go until the number $i=3$ ?

Comment: Perhaps because it assumes the context you're working within is $\mathbb{R}^3$? Otherwise, I don't see why simplifying the expressions as the more general $\delta_{ik} u_k = u_i$ and $\delta_{ij} \delta_{ij} = \delta_{ii}$ is wrong.

Comment: Because the notation seems to silently employ the Einstein summation convention and 3D space

Comment: Thanks both, got it now. Couldn't see why it would be simplified to this, but yes now it makes sense to be like that since it's a applied mathematics in mechanics course, which means 3D Space. Though, nothing about a space was mentioned. Thanks !